# Does SQL Server Cache Aggregate Results When Duplicated Across Columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose we have a table `Orders` containing the columns `order_id, total, discount`

Then we write a query similar to the following

```
SELECT
    COUNT(order_id) AS num_orders
    , SUM(total) / COUNT(order_id) as avg_total
    , SUM(discount) / COUNT(order_id) AS avg_discount
FROM Orders
```

Is the value for `COUNT(order_id)` Preserved across columns or re-computed (Eg, is there a performance hit)? Or is it better to determine the computed value(s) first and used those in the query, for example:

```
DECLARE @order_count AS INT 

SELECT 
    @order_count = COUNT(order_id) 
FROM Orders

SELECT
    @order_count AS num_orders
    , SUM(total) / @order_count as avg_total
    , SUM(discount) / @order_count AS avg_discount
FROM Orders
```

Note that, while writing this question I noticed that since SQL Server 2008 `AVG()` is supported. However, I continued this question and intend this to be more general to wanting to understand how SQL server handles Identical aggregates across columns as I do sometimes run into this in other forms.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880519/4137916).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Server only calculates the `COUNT` once. You can see this by looking at the properties of the execution plan for

```
create table Orders(order_id int, total int, discount int)


SELECT
    COUNT(order_id) AS num_orders
    , SUM(total) / COUNT(order_id) as avg_total
    , SUM(discount) / COUNT(order_id) AS avg_discount
FROM Orders
```

[image]

The stream aggregate (1) has the following defined values

```
[Expr1008] = Scalar Operator(COUNT([tempdb].[dbo].[Orders].[order_id])), 
[Expr1009] = Scalar Operator(COUNT_BIG([tempdb].[dbo].[Orders].[total])), 
[Expr1010] = Scalar Operator(SUM([tempdb].[dbo].[Orders].[total])), 
[Expr1011] = Scalar Operator(COUNT_BIG([tempdb].[dbo].[Orders].[discount])), 
[Expr1012] = Scalar Operator(SUM([tempdb].[dbo].[Orders].[discount]))
```

`Expr1008` is the calculation of the `COUNT` that you ask about.

There are some other `COUNT` aggregates for the other two columns. These are needed because the correct result for `SUM(total)` (for example) if `COUNT(total)` is `0` should be `NULL`.

This is carried out by the next compute scalar along (2). This also converts the `COUNT` result (`Expr1008`) from `bigint` to `int` and labels that as `Expr1003`

```
[Expr1003] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1008],0)),
[Expr1004] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [Expr1009]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1010] END), 
[Expr1005] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [Expr1011]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1012] END)
```

Finally the left most compute scalar (3) uses `Expr1003` in the division operation...

```
[Expr1006] = Scalar Operator([Expr1004]/[Expr1003]), 
[Expr1007] = Scalar Operator([Expr1005]/[Expr1003])
```

... and outputs columns `Expr1003, Expr1006, Expr1007` as the final result

PS: `AVG` has been supported much longer than SQL Server 2008. I imagine it has likely been available in the beginning. However it does not have the same semantics as your rewrite in the presence of `NULL`s anyway.

I assume `order_id` is the primary key and therefore not nullable but for a table with 10 orders and two `NOT NULL` `total` values of `2` and `4` then `AVG(total)` would be `3` but `SUM(total) / COUNT(order_id)` would be `0.6` (or `0` once integer division is taken into account).

Answer (score 4):

It should be calculated only once.  Here's little test that shows that even if the aggregate calls a UDF, it's not re-executed in every expression in which it appears.

```
use tempdb
go
create or alter function slow(@ms int)
returns int
as
begin

  declare @buf varbinary(max) = cast( replicate(cast(0x as nvarchar(max)),1000*1000*20) as varbinary(max))
  declare @start datetime2 = sysdatetime()

  while datediff(ms,@start,sysdatetime()) < @ms
  begin
     declare @hash binary(256) = hashbytes('sha_256',@buf)     
  end
  return 42;
end 
go
set statistics time on
go
select max(dbo.slow(10)) a
from sys.objects 

select max(dbo.slow(10)) a, sin(max(dbo.slow(10))) b, max(dbo.slow(10))/500 c, count(*) + max(dbo.slow(10)) d
from sys.objects
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to optimize for things that aren't necessary to optimize. Consider these queries:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT SUM(OrderQty)/COUNT(SalesOrderID) FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail; -- scans once

SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID),
 SUM(OrderQty)/COUNT(SalesOrderID),
 SUM(ProductID)/COUNT(SalesOrderID),
 SUM(UnitPriceDiscount)/COUNT(SalesOrderID),
 MIN(OrderQty)/COUNT(SalesOrderID),
 MAX(OrderQty)/COUNT(SalesOrderID)
 FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail; -- still only scans once

DECLARE @order_count AS INT 
 SELECT @order_count = COUNT(SalesOrderID) 
 FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail; -- scans once

SELECT @order_count,
 SUM(OrderQty)/@order_count,
 SUM(ProductID)/@order_count,
 SUM(UnitPriceDiscount)/@order_count,
 MIN(OrderQty)/@order_count,
 MAX(OrderQty)/@order_count
 FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail; -- has to scan again
```

The cost of scanning the entire table once just to get the count and then scanning again to use that count in operations within the second scan is definitely more trouble than it's worth. This is obvious in both the plans and the stats I/O, even on a very small table:

> -- first query - 7 reads
>   
> Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 1, **logical reads 7**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   
>   
> -- second query - still just 7 reads
>   Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 1, **logical reads 7**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   
>   
> -- variable + last two queries - 11 reads
>   
> Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 1, **logical reads 4**, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 1, **logical reads 7**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

If you're going to be reusing the count in multiple queries, queries against different tables, or queries where you're not otherwise going to have to scan (joins, filtered queries etc.), then it's a different question, potentially. But you shouldn't be concerned that the count will happen more than once during a single scan; as others have demonstrated, it won't. To justify pulling that count out of the query you'd have to have other scenarios happening.

Comment: That's what I was hoping, but wasn't sure of. :) I grew up in MySQL and only recently have started doing any serious work with SQL Server, and I often find SQL Server query plans overwhelming compared to what I'm used to looking at in MySQL so I'm still getting used to inspecting them.

Comment: @DavidScherer you will come to appreciate the power of a *real* query optimizer!